# When using TOAD on Windows 7, it pops up an error: ORA-06413 : Connection Not Open

Tags: oracle, toad, windows64

When using **TOAD** on Windows 7, it pops up an error:

`ORA-06413 : Connection Not Open`

I have **Windows 7 64-bit** and i can ping to the db ip .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the installation directory in path

**Quest Software**
from `C:\Program Files(x86)` **to** `C:\Program Files`

Answer (score 0):

STEP-1 Copy the installation directory of **Quest Software** from **C:\Program Files(x86)** to **C:\Program Files**.

STEP-2 Start Toad.exe from new directory!
( Create a new shortcut from new directory )